# Kernel virtual memory space and process virtual memory space

Tags: memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, virtualization

I was reading the textbook:Computer Systems A Programmer’s Perspective, in chapter 9.7.2:Linux Virtual Memory System (third edition) that talks about virtual memory.

I was a bit confused by the structure of virtual memory for linux process as shown below:

[image: memory schematic]

My question is: does kernel virtual memory preserve for kernel to run
and rest of the virtual memory preserve for user process? What does kernel code and data do? And what does the physical memory in kernel virtual memory?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question to be clearer? I don't think I understand what you mean by *"why we need to copy the kernel code and data for each process and what does physical memory in the kernel do?"*

Comment: Also, could you provide the name/author of the textbook? That image is pretty strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> does kernel virtual memory preserve for kernel to run and rest of the virtual memory preserve for user process?

Yes, there is a part of virtual memory that is always reserved for the kernel and another part that is left available to userspace processes. Every single process has its own virtual memory, but the kernel is always mapped in the higher part (higher addresses) of virtual memory. Whether or not this mapping is visible to the process depends on [Kernel Page Table Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_page-table_isolation).

See also: [Do the virtual address spaces of all the processes have the same content in their “Kernel” parts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469016)

> What does kernel code and data do?

Part of the high virtual memory is a direct mapping of the actual kernel image. That is, the kernel executable and all its data. You can see it in more detail here in [this page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt) of the kernel documentation, marked as *"kernel text mapping, mapped to physical address 0"*.

See also: [What's the use of having a kernel part in the virtual memory space of Linux processes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/472223)

> And what does the physical memory in kernel virtual memory?

That part of the image is totally misleading. I don't know precisely what information the authors of the book were trying to convey, but physical memory is definitely *not* a part of kernel virtual memory. They were probably trying to address the fact that there is a direct *mapping* of all physical memory in the kernel virtual memory, which can be seen again on [the same page](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt) of the kernel documentation, marked as *"direct mapping of all physical memory"*.

Physical memory refers to the *real* memory of the system (i.e. the RAM). Each region of virtual memory is mapped to some region of physical memory. This virtual-to-physical mapping is totally transparent to processes and is managed by the kernel. For example, two executables that have the same file open in read-only mode are usually sharing the same *physical* memory region, while seeing two different *virtual* address.

This is a more accurate depiction of the relationship between virtual and physical memory:

[image: virtual memory mapping]

Source: https://computationstructures.org/lectures/vm/vm.html

Comment: Thanks,I have two questions left. I don't understand why each process need to load the kernel executable and all its data to it's virtual address. And the motivation to design the direct mapping of all physical memory in the virtual memory.

Comment: @yi_li read the post I linked: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/472229/272806

Answer (score 0):

cited from the CSAPP book, 3rd version, section 9.7.2, where the picture is shown.

> Interestingly, **Linux also maps a set of contiguous virtual pages (equal in size to the total amount of DRAM in the system) to the corresponding set of contiguous physical pages**. This provides the kernel with a convenient way to access any speciﬁc location in physical memory—for example, when it needs to access page tables or to perform memory-mapped I/O operations on devices that are mapped to particular physical memory locations.

I think the `Physical memory` in the picture just reflects what's described above: a virtual memory area that maps to the entire physical memory.